# django foreign key

Tags: django

I have the following in my `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models

class LabName(models.Model):
    labsname=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    def __unicode__(self):
     return self.labsname

class ComponentDescription(models.Model):
       lab_Title=models.ForeignKey('Labname')
       component_Name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
       description = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        purchased_Date = models.DateField()
       status = models.CharField(max_length=30)
       to_Do = models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True) 
       remarks = models.CharField(max_length=30)

       def __unicode__(self):
           return self.component
```

I have the following in my `admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from Lab_inventory.models import ComponentDescription,LabName

class ComponentDescriptionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display= ('lab_Title','component_Name','description','purchased_Date','status','to_Do','remarks')          
    list_filter=('lab_Title','status','purchased_Date')

admin.site.register(LabName)
admin.site.register(ComponentDescription,ComponentDescriptionAdmin)
```

What I want is to display the fields under the component description to be displayed under the lab title(the fields related to each lab title by should be displayed under that lab name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing with `list_display` and `list_filter` pertain to the list that is shown in the admin screen where the list of LabName objects are listed.

Assuming one `LabName` has one-to-many `ComponentDescription` entities, you need Django's [`InlineModelAdmin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) to display the list of `ComponentDescription` objects belonging to `LabName` within the admin page for a specific `LabName` entity. The code would be of the following structure:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from Lab_inventory.models import ComponentDescription,LabName

class ComponentDescriptionInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ComponentDescription

class LabNameAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        ComponentDescriptionInline,
    ]

admin.site.register(LabName, LabNameAdmin)
```

where `TabularInline` is a subclass of the generic `InlineModelAdmin`.